# ld: framework not found Bolts for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I try to compile in Delphi **Rio** a project that was working fine under Delphi **tokyo**. I can't because I always have this error :

```
ld: framework not found Bolts for architecture armv7
```

But in the global delphi library path I have correctly set:

```
C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework
```

that is the path where is located the Bolts framework:

```
C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework\Headers\...
C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework\Modules\...
C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework\Info.plist
C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework\Bolts
```

What did I miss ?

Note: If I move the `C:\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework\` dir inside the global **PlateformSDKs** dir then it works.

Comment: This is a bug https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22216

Comment: Thanks @DalijaPrasnikar! Sad because you created this bug report on the 14/Oct/18 before the update 1 but it's still not resolved :( did you found a workaround ?

Comment: Workaround - add frameworks from Frameworks path to Search path in your project options. I haven't tried with global settings.

Comment: H@DalijaPrasnikar not sure i Understand, what is Frameworks path?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think I understand, by framework path you mean tool > deployement > SDK manager. I never add any external framework here, I always add the path to external framework in the Search path of the project option :( and as you see it's not work

Comment: No. Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Framework Search Path - this one does not work, but  Project Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Search Path works for me - for Firebase. I never tried other frameworks.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: wooow I never saw this option, Framework search path! I learn something :) I was always using the search path and so I can confirm you it's not work in the search path (at least with Facebook, but seem to work with firebase)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: I found a way out and updated your quality report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22216

Comment: You can also add answer here.

Answer (score 2):

i found a way out:

If I have

```
C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook\Bolts.framework
C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook\FBSDKCoreKit.framework
C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook\FBSDKLoginKit.framework
C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook\FBSDKShareKit.framework
```

I must add in the search path all those directories AND in the project option framework path the ROOT path

```
C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook\
```

then it's work! I still have a warning

> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied
>   'C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework
>   linker option at C:\Dev\Alcinoe\lib\ios\facebook/Bolts.framework/Bolts
>   is not a dylib

but it's work

Answer (score 0):

I include the Facebook SDK this way:

1) Copy all FBSDK frameworks into the active SDK. For iOS 12.1 it is:
`D:\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS12.1.sdk\System\Library\Frameworks`

2) Tell the Delphi linker to include the SDK.

Under `Project Options > Building > Delphi Compiler > Linking > Options passed to the LD linker`, add this line:

```
-ObjC -lz -framework FBSDKCoreKit -weak_framework Bolts
```